# Codeigniter modify database query array item

Tags: php, database, arrays, codeigniter

I'm attempting to modify a date field from my database before it gets outputted to the view, but I'm not having much luck.  This code doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
function get_journal_entry($id)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM journal WHERE user_id = '.$this->tank_auth->get_user_id().' AND id = '.$id;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        $query['created'] = date("c", strtotime($query['created']));


        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db->query` returns a query object, not your results.  You need to modify the row *after* calling `$query->row_array`.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->row_array();
$result['created'] = date("c", strtotime($result['created']));
return $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the code, which may work:

```
function get_journal_entry($id)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM journal WHERE user_id = ' . intval($this->tank_auth->get_user_id()) . ' AND id = ' . intval($id);
    $row = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
    $row['created'] = date("c", strtotime($row['created']));
    return $row;
}
```